# How to save a json object with variable keys to mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently learning Nodejs/Mongodb. My "small" projects contains getting data from an REST API, and write it into a mongodb.

First, the mongoose part:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SummonerSchema = new Schema({

    id : Number,
    name : String, 
    profileIconId : Number,
    revisionDate : Number,
    summonerLevel : Number

});

var Summoner = mongoose.model('Summoner', SummonerSchema);
```

I'm getting data from an REST API, which looks like this:

JSON Response

```
{
    "23741875": {
        "summonerLevel": 30,
        "profileIconId": 785,
        "revisionDate": 1489937599000,
        "id": 23741875,
        "name": "iP0ke"
    }
}
```

Apparently, this is not working, since I have no clue how to address the "23741875" correctly. What I get when running this is:

```
{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"23741875\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Summoner\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"23741875\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"23741875","path":"_id"}
```

What would be the best approach to solve this? What did I miss? Thanks in advance and apologies for asking a beginner question!

Comment: What's your  mongoose version?

Comment: Mongoose version is 4.4.12

Comment: why are you using this id : Number ?

Comment: I want to take the whole JSON object from the response and write it into the db. Therefore, I added id: Number, since I'm getting it in the response. Is that not correct?

Comment: Try changing your schema field id : Number to recordId: Number the assign value to this. more info http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id

Comment: I changed to id field to recordId. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved it ... I changed the schema to the following:

```
var SummonerSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name : String, 
    profileIconId : Number,
    summonerLevel : Number
     });
```

As for the create part, what I did was

```
for (var key in SummonerDto){
    Summoner.create({
       _id : SummonerDto[key].id,
       name : SummonerDto[key].name,
       profileIconId : SummonerDto[key].profileIconId,
       summonerLevel : SummonerDto[key].summonerLevel
    }, function(err){
       if(err)
          console.log(err);
    });
 }
```

This works perfectly now, although I'm aware that I now have to manage the_ids myself. However, the REST API where I get the data from guarantees, that the id will be  unique.